# Current text selection in CustomKeyBoardExtension

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uiinputviewcontroller, ios8-extension

I'm trying to write **`Custom Keyboard Extension`**.

I'm looking for the way to know where the cursor is on `UITextField`,`UITextView`...etc in **CustomKeyboardExtension** ... but I don't see anything like that.

I saw SwiftKey app (http://swiftkey.com) can do that (or do something like that). When I change the cursor, suggestion-text will change (see below pictures).

**Q:** How can we get current text selection?

...

**UPDATE: 29/09/2014**

Ok, I'm so foolish. We can use `documentContextBeforeInput`, `documentContextAfterInput` methods of `textDocumentProxy` property. I thought that "Before","After" are about the time. Actually it's about the position.

Sorry all! I wasted your time :(

Comment: `textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput`

Comment: Just 'documentContextBeforeInput' and 'documentContextAfterInput' don't cut it either. if the user opens a text that is auto selected, both will be empty, but there is definitely text in the field.

Answer (score 1):

Create lastWordBeforeInput method...

```
-(NSString *) lastWordBeforeInput{
    NSArray *arrayOfSplitsString = [self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    int countIndex = arrayOfSplitsString.count - 1;
    NSCharacterSet *ChSet = [NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet];
    NSCharacterSet *invertedChSet = [ChSet invertedSet];
    while (countIndex > 0) {
        NSString *lastWordOfSentance = [arrayOfSplitsString objectAtIndex:countIndex--];
        if ([[lastWordOfSentance stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:invertedChSet] rangeOfCharacterFromSet:ChSet].location != NSNotFound) {
            return [lastWordOfSentance stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        }
    }

    return @"";
}
```

Then call it with textWillChange/textDidChange as per requirement.

```
- (void)textWillChange:(id<UITextInput>)textInput {
    // The app is about to change the document's contents. Perform any preparation here.
    NSLog(@"%@",[self lastWordBeforeInput]);
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Does not answer the question: "Q: How can we get current text selection?"